# Check if RSA has been configured for SSH

Tags: linux, shell, encryption, rsa

I have installed/configured RSA encryption between my server A and client B with user X. My script works just fine when i execute it as user X but i would also like to consider different scenarios
   1. if user Y executes the script it prompts for password authentication instead i want script to throw an error and move on.
   2. if client C has not been configured with server A (rsa encryption), i would like to thrown an different error and move on.

Current Script

```
ssh $server_name 'mcell -q -n "'"$i"'" ' || echo " Failed to SSH "
```

Question:
1. Can i be able to check whether RSA is installed before SSH ?
2. Can i be able to check on which user RSA is installed at client before calling SSH ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA (like DSA and ECDSA) is an asymmetric cipher built into SSH, so there's nothing to "install". You probably mean you generated an RSA key pair for your user X and use that key pair for public key authentication against server A.

By default SSH supports a variety of authetication mechanisms, of which public key authentication is only one (see `man sshd`, section AUTHENTICATION):

> Finally, the server and the client enter an authentication dialog. The client tries to authenticate itself using host-based authentication, public key authentication, challenge-response authentication, or password authentication.

The available authentication methods are tried in order, meaning that public key authentication is tried before password authentication.

If you run `ssh -v` with your user X, you'll get debug output like this:

```
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/X/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to servera ([192.168.23.42]:22).
...
```

whereas for the user Y the output would look like this:

```
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Y/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
Y@servera's password:
```

User Y doesn't have a private key, so that authentication method fails and password authentication is tried next. To prevent that you need to add the following lines to the server's `sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

and restart the `sshd`. After the restart login attempts by user Y will fail with a "permission denied" error:

```
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Y/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

You could also disable password authentication on the client-side, either for a specific user by creating a file `/home/Y/.ssh/config`, or for all users in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (*not* `sshd_config`):

```
Host *
  PasswordAuthentication no
```

Replace `*` with a hostname if you want to limit that restriction to a specific host.